# Parsing JSON into NSMutableDictionary issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `JSON` response of the below format & I parse it into a `NSMutableDictionary` , which again I am trying to filter into separate dictionaries.For example, from the below response I want to make a membersDictionary out of the whole `JSON` response but can't find a way to do it.

```
[
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "lat": "45.747711",
                "lng": "4.824100"
            },
            {
                "lat": "47.747711",
                "lng": "3.824100"
            }
        ],
        "professionnels": [
            {
                "lat": "45.747711",
                "lng": "4.824100"
            },
            {
                "lat": "47.747711",
                "lng": "3.824100"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is how I make a separate dictionary out of the whole response.

```
NSMutableArray *latArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *lngArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *obj in self.jsonDictionary) //this is NSMutableDictionary which contains whole response.
{
    _membersDict = [obj objectForKey:@"members"];

    for (NSDictionary *obj in _membersDict)
    {
        NSString *latitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *longitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lng"];

        [latArray addObject:latitudeString];
        [lngArray addObject:longitudeString];
    }
}
NSLog(@"members dict  fetched %@", _membersDict);  // SHOWS NULL 
NSLog(@"latitude array - %@", latArray);           // shows values
NSLog(@"longitude array - %@", lngArray);          // shows values
```

Comment: How did you populate the self.jsonDictionary?

Comment: So I assume that `_jsonDictionary` and `_membersDict` are arrays, like in your JSON, right?

Comment: jsonDictioanry and membersDict .... both are NSMutableDictionary

Comment: They shouldn't! In your JSON it's arrays. But nevermind, event though you declared them as Dict, they get casted to array... Youo can check this with `NSSStringFromClass([obj class])` Strange issue though, I tested the code and it works...

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if you can parse that into an NSMutableDictionary, since the outermost structure is an array.  See json.org for the (very easy to understand) JSON syntax.

Comment: Of course, even though you mislabeled the two arrays, the above code sorta works, since `for...in` loops don't care about that.

Comment: can you please show what NSLog outputs look like?

Comment: Like u said....I changed self.jsonDictionary to NSMutableArray and then fetched [objectForKey:@"members"]; from that....and now it has the members Dictionary   ...   :-] ..

Comment: When you're first learning JSON, *always* NSLog *every* step along the way.  And observe that if the *outermost* bracketing characters are `()` that's a dictionary, while if they are `[]` that's an array.  (Observe carefully, though, since most folks tend to disregard the outermost bracketing characters.)

Comment: Oops -- got that slightly wrong -- `()` is an array and `{}` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON have array of dictionaries, so first cast it to array and loop over the array. In each iteration you will have a dictionary and then you can access them.
[] shows array.

```
 for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray){
    //Now your dic store key value, and value is again in array
    NSArray *memberArray = [dic objectForKey:@"member"];
    //memberArray contain dictionarys
    for (NSDictionary *memDic in memberArray){
    NSString *lat = memDic objectForKey:@"lat"];
    //and same for other value
    }
    //Now do the same for professional

    }
```

Comment: okay...In my case I have NSMutableDictionary (self.jsonDictionary) which has whole response...So should I make it an array instead?

Comment: Yes, because you are getting array in json response

Comment: It actually doesn't matter at this point. Later you he should, because he won't be able to compile. But actually, even if declared as dict, the object gets casted to array. So this is not the reason why it's not working for him

Comment: Things should be in right way, we know some selectors will respond to both array and dictionary and there will be no issue. But we should it is possible in future he makes same mistake and try to call some NSDictionary specific selector on the array, which may cause a crash. same is true for vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way is to use KVC Collection Operators:

```
NSArray *latArray = [self.jsonDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.members.lat"];
NSArray *lngArray = [self.jsonDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.members.lng"];
```